# Build an PhoneGap app with Apache Ant

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, ant, cordova

I want to create a automated build process with Ant to compress the JavaScript files of my PhoneGap application and create a build for deployment. I am a newbie with Ant, is there any step by step guide somewhere on how to use it with PhoneGap?

Comment: What you mean is to recompile jar for phonegap-android? The code is from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android

Answer (score 0):

I set it up from you tube.  You want to use install ant on windows as search or soemthing.  I think this one is good, if not monotone:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJmndRfb1TU

Maybe follow it with an in depth phonegap tut: 
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-BlackBerry-WebWorks

Answer (score -3):

Well, [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) is perhaps the best tutorial that you can find. From Apache Ant. And it comes with examples for each task. :)

Comment: i m looking specific for PhoneGap Android App